# Can't change theme of Windows 2008 server to look like Windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-service

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server which I try to change its theme to Windows-7 a-like by the following procedure: http://www.win2008r2workstation.com/themes/

I have the following problem: "Themes" service seems to be running. However, when I try to choose another theme, I get an error message that says this service is not running.

Please advice.

Thank you

Comment: Did you install the manufacturer video card driver?

Comment: It's a virtual machine, hosted in a cloud. Do you think its necessary?

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting via RDP: You'll have to configure both your RDP client and the Server to allow themes over RDP. On the client it's as easy as Options->Experience->All Checked. For the sever search "RDP Enable Themes" or [check out these directions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/06/23/aero-glass-remoting-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx). Note: Aero Glass over the Internet is going to lag a bit (or a lot, depending on your connection).